# Android Studio - Run App not showing on device

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed Android Studio, connected the phone to the computer with a USB cable, and Android Studio shows my phone model on the modal when clicking **Run**. when I click to run the app on my device, it doesn't show me any errors. What it says to me in the console is:

```
09/18 13:47:00: Launching 'app' on Samsung SM-A528B.
Install successfully finished in 311 ms.
Timed out waiting for the process (com.example.test) to appear on samsung-sm_a528b-CTF21AS12SK7QF.
```

When I click again play button I got only this in the console:

```
09/18 13:53:51: Launching 'app' on Samsung SM-A528B.
Install successfully finished in 294 ms.
```

Can someone explain to me what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you verify launch options? `Run > Edit Configurations > yourApp > Launch Options > Default Activity`

Comment: It's the default. I create an empty project and start to run it without any changes. @ocos